# How to "map" JSON datas into a class without a database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to "map" JSON datas retrieved from an application (*APP1*) into a class of another application (*APP2*).

In few words the *APP2* make an HTTP request to the *APP1* and the *APP1* send back JSON datas. The *APP2* should receive this datas and create a new class populated of that datas just for its internal usage. The class in *APP2* should not have a database table but is very usefull if that has all advantages of an ActiveRecord.

> *What I need basically is to handle the information retrieved from APP1 as
>   an ActiveRecord in APP2.*

**What do you advice? What I have to do?**

Comment: Do you control both apps? If yes: It would be easier to have App1 respond with XML and have an ActiveResource model in App2. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lot of the nice features of ActiveRecord without ActiveRecord since most of them have been moved to ActiveModel. For example:

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  attr_accessor :attributes
end

user = User.new.from_json %q{ { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe" } }
puts user
```

That said, @Wukerplank makes a good point. ActiveResource can be a really easy way to hook up 2 rails apps if you control the api.